# Writing a trigger to update a value with a value from its own row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have the following table..

```
CREATE TABLE `community_data_1` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    `reply_to_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `subject` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `post` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
    `html` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `time_stamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `author_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `d_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

Now whenever an insert is done, after the insert I need to check if the d_id value is set to zero, if it is then I need to update it to the same value as that of the id of that row. How do I do this?

Comment: http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=how+to+write+an+update+trigger+in+mysql&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a17560d1ef61d5f5&biw=1280&bih=675

Comment: and you need a trigger which executes after every insert. then from the trigger update the table. but beware of the infinite loop!

Answer (score 1):

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER fixValue BEFORE INSERT ON community_data_1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF NEW.d_id = 0 THEN
        SET @NewId= (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM community_data_1);
        SET NEW.d_id = NewId;
    END IF;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed I am getting the following error. can't update table "community_data_1" in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14887 - this link suggests that it's a bug in mysql, sorry (although other databases support it, at least PostgreSQL does). See the edit.

Comment: BEFORE insert? I think the trigger should get executed after insert right?

Comment: No, the trigger will execute before insert, and that's ok because just before inserting a new row, you are checking whether or not d_id is zero. If it is, then you are changing it's value to the corresponding id and saving it into the DB once and for all, no extra update is needed. This should work.

Comment: No its not working.... Its showing no error but its not updating the d_id value.. i am using MySQL 5.1.41

Comment: Then see another edit, but I myself don't like the approach. You better either use a procedure to insert those values into the table, or perform this check in the upper layer rather than in DB layer. If it doesn't work, then I really don't know what else to do and I will delete my answer myself.

Comment: Well the sad news is, its popping an error message saying there is some syntax error near "(SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM community_data_1);
    END IF;
  END;" Doing it at an upper layer rather than the DB layer seems so lame.. that is why i am in search of a trigger.

Comment: try which one?? didn't get you?

Comment: it is showing an error...when a new value is inserted... d_id cannot be null...  :(

Comment: sasidhar: d_id cannot be null because you have declared it to be not null. Are you sure you are sending not null values from upper layer ?